# Why is my child height: 100% not pixel perfect?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple loading bar here:

https://codepen.io/Ha1fDead/pen/LjKpjQ

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: teal;
  border: 6px solid black; 
}

.progress-bar-shade {   
  width: 66%;   
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-bar-shade">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On my 1080p monitor display in Chrome, this displays just fine:

[image: Correct display]

However on my 1440p monitor display, there is a visual error:

[image: Clips outside of child bounds]

(Note the 1px above and below the background that clips onto the border of the parent).

[image: Another Example, note 1px short on the top]

(Another graphical error after zooming in)

I can alter the problem (even replicating it on the 1080 display) by using the browser controls to zoom in. In these cases, sometimes the shade color is 1px short (the teal background is visible on the bottom). I've noticed this on all directions (top border, left border, right border, and bottom border). The only browser I cannot replicate this with is Firefox, which always displays correctly.

Specifying `box-sizing: border-box` alters the behavior somewhat, but zooming in causes the same issue.

What is causing this pixel imperfection and how can I correct it?

Comment: The gaps are caused by pixel rounding errors in the rendering engine. It looks to me (in your CodePen) that the overlap isn't solidly red or teal, but a blend of both colors.

Comment: I had a similar assumption, but have no idea how to either fix it or work around it. Any ideas?

Checking hex values of my last image (from the codepen using chrome debugger colour picker)...

RED: #ff0000;
TEAL# 008080;
BORDER-RIGHT: #605050 (blended);
BORDER-TOP (bottom pixel of blend): #8b3a3a;
BLENDED-TOP (top pixel of blend): #002727;

Comment: This may just be an unavoidable result of the design. See if different colors, or a different arrangement of them, solves the problem for you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Chromium on KDE. No amout of zooming causes the rectangles to be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually to do with `border`, using `outline` instead solves your problem. It's almost certainly a rounding error as you deduced in the comments.

When using `border`, 12px is added to the height and width of the object. However when you zoom, that 12px and the outer div are multiplied separately and then combined. This means that the height of the inner div is dependant upon the displayed thickness of the border. Whereas when using `outline` the inner div doesn't care about the thickness of the border as that is applied after, and can simply copy the exact height of the outer div. This would also explain why the glitch is less prominent when the border is thinner.

Regardless of the reasoning, here's your code using `outline` instead:

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: teal;
  outline: 6px solid black;
}

.progress-bar-shade {
  width: 66%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="progress-bar-container">
    <div class="progress-bar">
      <div class="progress-bar-shade">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```